# Frame.GoBack() succeeds on UI button click, fails on Windows software back button callback

Tags: c#, uwp, navigation, windows-10-universal

I have a language-learning app with the following basic page navigation structure:

1. **Start** - App title screen
2. **Languages** - List of languages
3. **Lessons** - List of lessons for selected language
4. **Activities** - Page with activities to work on for selected lesson

The first three pages each have a button that navigates to the next page with a call similar to:

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => Frame.Navigate(typeof(SomePage));
```

On the Activities page, after a user submits his last correct answer with a button press, the app navigates back like this:

```
private async void SubmitAnswer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...

    if (answerCorrect && allActivitiesComplete)
    {
        Frame.GoBack();
        return;
    }

    ...
}
```

This **works**; I am returned to the Lessons page. If I hover over `Frame` with IntelliSense, I see the `BackStack` property has a count of 3, one for each of the previous pages.

However, I also want to display the software back button. To do this I have the following code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    ...
    var nav = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
    nav.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
    ...
}
```

Good, now the button shows in the top left in desktop-mode. But pressing it does nothing. So I update with the following:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    ...
    var nav = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
    nav.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
    nav.BackRequested += (x, y) =>
    {
        Frame.GoBack();
    };
    ...
}
```

This **fails** with:

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

`Frame.BackStack` shows a count of `0` and `Frame.CanGoBack` is `false`. Why is this code flow inconsistent with the button press code flow?

Comment: The app level back button should be registered at *App level* or if your app uses navigation view then in the page which has the logic for the navigation (generally the MainPage) , so that the navigation stack and the frame you are referring to are always the same in order to maintain consistency throughout the app. Also, before actually calling `Frame.GoBack()` it is a good idea to check if the backstack actually has any pages `if(Frame.CanGoBack){ // go back }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ideally wire up the `BackRequested` event globally, not in the scope of a specific page. This is because if you add an event handler `OnNavigatedTo`, you will add another each time the page is navigated. This means that clicking the back button will navigate back several times. Also it will **keep all the pages** that attached the handler **in memory**, which is a **serious memory leak**. At the very least you should switch from using a lamda to an event handler method and unsubscribe it in `OnNavigatedFrom`.

To implement app title bar back button properly you should do this:

1. Observe the `Frame` `Navigated` method, to show/hide the back button as appropriate based on the `CanGoBack` property
2. In the `BackRequested` handler check for `CanGoBack` to make sure the navigation is possible

An example of the implementation for a blank UWP app would be as follows:

Add the following methods to your `App.xaml.cs`:

```
private void SetupAppBarBackButton()
{
    _rootFrame.Navigated += RootFrame_Navigated;
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += App_BackRequested;
}

private void App_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_rootFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        _rootFrame.GoBack();
    }
}

private void RootFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
        _rootFrame.CanGoBack
           ? AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible
           : AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Also add a private `_rootFrame` field:

```
private Frame _rootFrame;
```

Finally update the `OnLaunched` method to store the root frame and setup the back button:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
    // just ensure that the window is active
    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        ...

        // Place the frame in the current Window
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;

        _rootFrame = rootFrame;
        SetupAppBarBackButton();
    }
    ...
}
```

Please note, that if you are creating the root frame somewhere else as well (like for other activation paths), you need to store the frame and call the `SetupAppBarBackButton` method there as well.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. The error would occur because the event handler would be created multiple times, and so the app would navigate back more pages than possible. The misunderstanding was with the lifecycle of the pages then.

I set up the back button once globally in App.xaml.cs and it works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped :-)! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    ...

    Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
    Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += (s,a) =>
    {

        if (Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            Frame.GoBack();
            a.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This helped me discover some issues while debugging; thank you.

Comment: Let me know if this is helpful and also you need more help.